# How to initialize JTable before fill it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, initialization

I'm writing a code for a JTable that contains search results from a DB, and I need to initialize it with no rows in each click on "doSort" button by setRowCount(0) method or by initTable() method, I've wrote the following code, but it does not work:

```
private void doSortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    try {
            ArrayList<String> all = null;
            String resStr = null;
            mail = new Mail();
            tm.setRowCount(0);
            initTable(tm);
            if(incomSelect.isSelected())
                try {
                    all = mail.select("SELECT * FROM mails WHERE type = 'incoming'");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                }
            else if(outcomSelect.isSelected())
                try {
                    all = mail.select("SELECT * FROM mails WHERE type = 'outcoming'");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                }

           for(int i=0; i<all.size(); i++) {
               resStr = all.get(i);
               String[] resArr =  resStr.split(",");
               tm.insertRow(i, resArr);
           }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
}
```

And initTable() code:

```
public void initTable(DefaultTableModel mod){
        for (int i = mod.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mod.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: See also [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: It might help to include more information about what is not working for you.